# Compare a part of text to a String

Tags: ios, swift, range

I'm trying to get the range of a text, I did this:

```
let telRange = Range(start: tfTelephone.text!.startIndex, end: tfTelephone.text!.endIndex.advancedBy(2))
```

After this I'm trying to compare:

```
if (telRange == "08")
```

But I get an error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'Range' (aka 'Range') and 'String'

Comment: U cant compare a range to a string, its clearly said so, either use that range to get the substring then compare or use predicate / regex to straight compare both text using structure

Comment: the `Range(...)` is not a `String`, c'mon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't force unwrap, use an `if-let` instead. Secondly, you can't compare a `Range` and a `String`, most likely you want to compare the substring for that range. And thirdly, you can't advance forward from the `endIndex`.

```
let telRange: String
if let text = tfTelephone.text {
    telRange = text[text.startIndex...text.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)]
} else {
    telRange = ""
}
```

Something like above should work, you can tweak the indexes and the `advanceBy` arguments to match your expectations.

Comment: I tryed to do a function     `func verifTel() -> String {
        let telRange: String
        if let text = tfTelephone.text {
            telRange = text[text.startIndex...text.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)]
        }
        return telRange
    }` but it says  Constant 'telRange' used before being initialized

Comment: @Ben you didn't added the `else` path from my answer, without it's expected for the compiler to complain, as there's a chance for `telRange` to not get initialized

Comment: It's return nothing, I want to get the 2 first characters: `func verifTel() -> String{
        let telRange: String
        if let text = tfTelephone.text {
            telRange = text[text.startIndex...text.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)]
        }
        else {
            telRange=""
        }
        return telRange
    }`

Comment: You can use then `text.startIndex.advance(2)` instead of the `endIndex` expression

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this instead:

```
if (tfTelephone.text![telRange] == "08") {
    // ...
}
```

However, before that will work you have to fix this:

```
let telRange = Range(
    start: tfTelephone.text!.startIndex, 
    end: tfTelephone.text!.endIndex.advancedBy(2) // <- This will fail.  Use negative
)                                                 //    number, and make sure to stay 
                                                  //    within the length of the input 
                                                  //    string still.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let yourString = tfTelephone.text
let telRange = Range(start: yourString!.startIndex, end: yourString!.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)) //It's important to use only negative numbers!
let stringToCompare = yourString!.substringWithRange(telRange)
```

Now you can compare the two strings

```
if (stringToCompare == "08")
```

Comment: It say Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(start: Index, end: Index)' and Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Range<Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')